# How to use imports in typescript package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have a problem with imports inside typescript package.

I have class `A` and class `B` inside models directory

so i'm importing B into A

```
import B from "models/B"

interface A {
   b: B
}

export default A;
```

but after build `A.d.ts` cannot see `B` interface.

I was trying to set `exports` inside `package.json` but it's still not working.

How to import interface into interface. I need to use these interfaces directry after install for example:

```
import A from "@space/my-package/models/A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You very probably have some [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) alias in your `tsconfig.json` to convert the absolute path `models/B` into an actual path on your system.

As described in TS doc about [module and paths resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#additional-module-resolution-flags): (emphasis mine)

> The TypeScript compiler has a set of additional flags to *inform* the compiler of transformations that are expected to happen to the sources to generate the final output.
>
> It is important to note that **the compiler will *not* perform any of these transformations**; it just uses these pieces of information to guide the process of resolving a module import to its definition file.

So it is like having 2 compilation systems, each with their own path resolution:

- TypeScript compilation, which uses flags in `tsconfig.json`, but compiles the paths *without changing them* in its output
- your project compilation (bundling, consumption, or even a new TypeScript compilation), which uses its own configuration (possibly its own `tsconfig.json` in case of TS again)

As explained in the doc, the TS flags in `tsconfig.json` are supposed to *reflect* what is done in the final compilation.

But if you configure some path alias in the module `tsconfig.json`, without having the corresponding counterpart in the consuming project, the latter will not be able to correctly resolve those paths.

As a general rule, avoid absolute paths in libraries/modules (that must be compiled and consumed by other projects), unless they reference packages that you know will be in a `node_modules` folder (and refer to them by their package name, do not attempt esoteric alias).